# Can JSF applications be configured to run without using internet connections?

Tags: jsf, xml-namespaces

Is it possible to configure JSF applications to run without internet access after deploying to local server?

```
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml
xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html
```

Would above XML namespaces pose any problem after deployment?

Comment: What JSF error are you getting at runtime?

Comment: Well, i am not getting any error after disconnecting internet connection. But I thought that if i deployed war file in some server, what would happen if that server had no internet connection?

Answer (score 6):

Those links don't require Internet access. They could just as well be gobbledygook. They're only there to provide a long enough namespace name so as to be unambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

Those are not-followed URLs for naming, without validation AFAIK.

For other external XML/DTD links you can use [XML catalogs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Catalog), which for XHTML heavily speeds up things (HTML has enormous entities). There you map URLs to local files copied from those URLs.